# Flutter how lo listen device dark theme change instantly

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter app doesnt listen user's preferences changes at dark theme feature. I need to hard restart my app to reflect the changes.

How to make my flutter theme change instantly once I turn on / off the dark theme in device setting?

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark
      ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you give this plugin [Adaptive Chameleon Theme](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_chameleon_theme) a try. It is designed to help you switch theme modes with ease be it from light to dark or even utilising the default user defined device theme.

Like so:

```
// sets theme mode to dark
AdaptiveChameleonTheme.of(context).changeThemeMode(dark: true);
  
// sets theme mode to light
AdaptiveChameleonTheme.of(context).changeThemeMode(dark: false);
  
// sets theme mode to system default
AdaptiveChameleonTheme.of(context).changeThemeMode(dynamic: true);
```

It also comes with the added benefit of allowing you to change the theme colours if you need to.

```
AdaptiveChameleonTheme.of(context).setTheme(AppThemes.LightRed);
AdaptiveChameleonTheme.of(context).setTheme(AppThemes.LightBlue);
```

The selections are stored in shared preferences and persisted in the device memory.

Full disclosure, I am the developer of the plugin so you can consider this a shameless plug. However, I too faced similar challenges in the past leading me to develop this quick and easy to use solution.

Answer (score 0):

To see the change you need two things, use `StatefulWidget` and call `setState` everytime user change theme.

```dart
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      functionToChangeTheme();
    });
  },
  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
)
```